# Why does this import give me an error message when trying to import from 2 local modules?

Tags: python, function, recursion, import, python-import

I have the following code structure:

```
Graph API/
│── main.py
├── helper_functions/
    ├── defines.py
    ├── insights.py
```

insights.py imports 2 functions from defines.py at the beginning:

```
from defines import getCreds, makeApiCall
```

It then uses "makeApiCall" for this function:

```
def getUserMedia( params ) :
    // Some code about url endpoints etc. 

    return makeApiCall( url, endpointParams, params['debug'] ) # make the api call
```

I want to use the getUserMedia function in the main.py script, so I import it with:

```
from helper_functions.insights import *
```

But I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Graph_API/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import helper_functions.insights
  File "/Users/Graph_API/helper_functions/insights.py", line 1, in <module>
    from defines import getCreds, makeApiCall
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'defines'
```

What leads to this error? When I use the getUserMedia function within insights.py it works fine. I already tried importing defines.py to main.py as well, but I get the same error.

I am pretty new to programming, so I would really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
from defines import getCreds, makeApiCall
```

With

```
from helper_functions.defines import getCreds, makeApiCall
```

Or

```
from .defines import getCreds, makeApiCall
```

You must give a path either from project directory as in the first example, or from the relative path from the insights file by adding a dot.

You could also consider adding **init**.py to the helper_functions folder. Checkout here: [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: But defines.py and insights.py are in the same directory. If I use "from helper_functions.defines import getCreds, makeApiCall", the import does not work. I tried adding a blank __init__.py in the helper_functions directory but this did not help. I think there is some recursion because insights.py imports from defines.py and main.py imports from both other files but I don't know how to fix that..